# Prepend Git commit message with partial branch name

Tags: regex, git, branch

My current branch naming convention is as such:

```
ticket-45-my-new-feature-branch-description
```

I am currently using this code in my .git/hooks/prepare-commit-msg file to prepend every commit message with the branch name as such:

```
BRANCH_NAME=$(git branch 2>/dev/null | grep -e ^* | tr -d ' *')
if [ -n "$BRANCH_NAME" ] && [ "$BRANCH_NAME" != "master" ]; then
    echo "[$BRANCH_NAME] $(cat $1)" > $1
fi
```

End result:

```
[ticket-45-my-new-feature-branch-description] test commit
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is output like this:

```
[ticket-45] test commit
```

Brownie points if we can capitalize it:

```
[TICKET-45] test commit
```

I would love to keep my descriptive branch names, but truncate the prepended text in commit messages. I'm sure I have to use some regex, but I really don't know how to accomplish that. I should mention that we have several projects going on at once, so branch names are different, like so:

```
ticket-123-branch-name
abc-22-my-branch
ua-11-my-feature
```

The only thing in common is the fact that I need everything before the second '-'.

Any help is greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: Hello. Could you publish the resulting script, after following the below pieces of advice?  Thanks!!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Ok, first, this:

```
BRANCH_NAME=$(git branch 2>/dev/null | grep -e ^* | tr -d ' *')
```

is major overkill :-)  Use:

```
branch=$(git symbolic-ref --short HEAD) || ...
```

to get the current branch name.  The part after `||` is "what to do if you're not on a branch" (i.e., if you're in "detached head" mode)—you'll have to decide that for yourself.  (Your current code sets BRANCH_NAME to the empty string; to do that, you don't even need the `||` part, but you may want to add `-q`, or a `2>/dev/null`, to avoid the "fatal:" message from symbolic-ref.)

The rest is just basic scripting.  In bash you can use regex's directly, in old sh you can invoke `expr` or `sed`.  Both `sed` and `tr` can upper-case-ify, but sed can do a regex too, so it looks like a good candidate:

```
$ trimmed=$(echo $branch | sed -e 's:^\([^-]*-[^-]*\)-.*:\1:' -e \
    'y/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz/ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ/')
$ echo $trimmed
TICKET-45
```

Last, it's slightly dangerous to do:

```
echo "some stuff $(cat $1)" > $1
```

as you're depending on the shell to expand the `$(cat $1)` before it truncates the output file for the `> $1` part.  (Obviously it works, but you're subject to shell vagaries.)  Better to use a temporary file, or maybe another `sed` but in-place:

```
sed -i .bak -e "1s:^:[$trimmed] :" $1
# or use -i '', but note minor warning in sed man pages
```

The above is only tested piecemeal, but should work.

Comment: The script posted above is most likely coming from my blog, so all shame on me. Thanks a lot torek for the detailed explanation. Now I can call myself "a bit better shell n00b" :) I will update my blog with your suggestions.

Comment: @bartosz.majsak: hey, everyone has to start somewhere :-)

Comment: `branch=$(git symbolic-ref --short HEAD)
$trimmed=$(echo $branch | sed -e 's/^\([^-]*-[^-]*\)-.*/\1/' -e \
   'y/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz/ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ/')
sed -i .bak -e "1s/^/[$trimmed] /" $1` - This produces such commit message: [] my commt message. What can be the reason?

Comment: @alex: your quote above has `$trimmed=` rather than `trimmed=` (but if I do that I get things like `=...: command not found` so I'm not sure that's in your original).

Comment: removed $ and now get `sed: 1: "1s/^/[FEATURE/PI-89] /
": bad flag in substitute command: 'P'`

Comment: @alex: ah, that's because `/` is a poorly-chosen substitute separator since `/` can appear in branch names.  I'll change it to a character that's forbidden in branch names.