# Git commit hook to prepend message

Tags: git, pre-commit-hook

I originally had a slightly different need and was given a great answer:
[Prepend Git commit message with partial branch name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19871484/prepend-git-commit-message-with-partial-branch-name/19871683)

However, my needs have changed a bit and the regex I have is not working as intended, I'm hoping someone can give me a little guidance.

My current branch naming convention is: `bug/ab-123/branch-description`

What I need to do is prepend every git commit message with the values in between each forward slash, so in this case `ab-123`. Additionally, I'd like it capitalized as `AB-123`.

The end result I'm looking for is:

```
AB-123 my commit message goes here
```

My current prepare-commit-message regex is:

```
branch=$(git symbolic-ref --short HEAD)

trimmed=$(echo "$branch" | sed -e 's:^[a-z]+\/\([a-z]{2,}-\d+\):\1:' -e \
    'y/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz/ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ/')

echo $trimmed | sed -e 's/f/b/' | tr [a-z] [A-Z] | awk '{print("ls " $1)}'
```

This does nothing however. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really need regular expressions if you've got a nice delimited string like that:

```
branch=$(git symbolic-ref --short HEAD)
trimmed=$(echo $branch | cut -f2 -d/ | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]')
```

So given:

```
$ git status
On branch bug/ab-123/foobar
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

We get:

```
$ branch=$(git symbolic-ref --short HEAD)
$ echo $branch
bug/ab-123/foobar
```

And:

```
$ trimmed=$(echo $branch | cut -f2 -d/ | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]')
$ echo $trimmed
AB-123
```

And this gives you "the values in between each forward slash", converted to uppercase.

Comment: This worked like a charm, thank you! I added this to the end to ensure my commit message was included: `echo "$trimmed $(cat $1)" > $1`